# Tkinter: my floating frame in python is flickering while i'm moving it with mouse

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-layout

Good Morning,
I'm a newbie python, and I would like to make a floating frame with tkinter, but I can't get it because when I drag it starts flickering.
any suggest:
here the code

`

```
from tkinter import *


class MyFrame(Frame):

    def __init__(self, root, w=300, h=300, x=100, y=200, bg="red"):
        Frame.__init__(self, root, width=w, height=h, bg=bg)
        self.place(x=x, y=y,)
        self.first_x = 0
        self.first_y = 0
        self.first_origin_x = 0
        self.first_origin_y = 0
        self.bind("<Button-1>", self.first_point)
        self.bind("<B1-Motion>", self.move)


    def first_point(self,e):
        self.first_x = e.x
        self.first_y = e.y
        self.first_origin_x = self.winfo_x()
        self.first_origin_y = self.winfo_y()
        


    def move(self, e):
        self.place(x=self.first_origin_x-(self.first_x-e.x), y=self.first_origin_y-(self.first_y-e.y))



root = Tk()
root.geometry("800x600")
myframe = MyFrame(root=root)


root.mainloop()
```

`

Thanks for helping

I would like to use it in a larger program in which I can move different parts of the gui as I want.

Answer (score 0):

You are close.

But for the `first_point` method you only need to set the location that you want to store for `x,y`

Then in `move` you can do all the math and moving.

The reason it was fluttering is because in your example the move method is deciding where to place the frame based on where it was when the button was pressed rather than where it is at the time of the calculation.

```
class MyFrame(Frame):

    def __init__(self, root, w=300, h=300, x=100, y=200, bg="red"):
        Frame.__init__(self, root, width=w, height=h, bg=bg)
        self.place(x=x, y=y,)
        self.bind("<Button-1>", self.first_point)
        self.bind("<B1-Motion>", self.move)

    def first_point(self,e):
        self.first_x = e.x
        self.first_y = e.y

    def move(self, e):
        dx = e.x - self.first_x + self.winfo_x()
        dy = e.y - self.first_y + self.winfo_y()
        self.place(x=dx, y=dy)
```